# Ubuntu 18.04 compilation fails while doing editconfigs for kernel version 5.4.0-66.74

Tags: 18.04, kernel

While compiling Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on a source code
I am getting these errors.

Steps followed

1. LANG=C fakeroot debian/rules clean
2. LANG=C fakeroot debian/rules editconfigs
3. Edited some config flags such through menu popup
4. LANG=C fakeroot debian/rules binary-headers binary-generic binary-perarch

After some time I got these errors on my terminal:
[..]

```
touch /averma/5.4.0-66.74/linux-5.4.0/debian/stamps/stamp-prepare-tree-generic
Debug: config-prepare-check-generic
check-config: /averma/5.4.0-66.74/linux-5.4.0/debian/build/build-generic/.config: loading config
check-config: /averma/5.4.0-66.74/linux-5.4.0/debian.master/config/annotations loading annotations
check-config: FAIL (y != n): CONFIG_DEBUG_WW_MUTEX_SLOWPATH policy<{'amd64': 'n', 'arm64': 'n', 'armhf': 'n', 'i386': 'n', 'ppc64el': 'n', 's390x': 'n'}>
check-config: FAIL (y != n): CONFIG_PAGE_OWNER policy<{'amd64': 'n', 'arm64': 'n', 'armhf': 'n', 'i386': 'n', 'ppc64el': 'n', 's390x': 'n'}>
check-config: FAIL (- != n): CONFIG_CIFS_SMB_DIRECT policy<{'amd64': 'n', 'arm64': 'n', 'armhf': 'n', 'i386': 'n', 'ppc64el': 'n', 's390x': 'n'}>
check-config: FAIL (y != n): CONFIG_DEBUG_KMEMLEAK policy<{'amd64': 'n', 'arm64': 'n', 'armhf': 'n', 'i386': 'n', 'ppc64el': 'n', 's390x': 'n'}>
check-config: FAIL (y != n): CONFIG_DEBUG_RWSEMS policy<{'amd64': 'n', 'arm64': 'n', 'armhf': 'n', 'i386': 'n', 'ppc64el': 'n', 's390x': 'n'}>
check-config: FAIL (5 != 0): CONFIG_PANIC_TIMEOUT policy<{'amd64': '0', 'arm64': '0', 'armhf': '0', 'i386': '0', 'ppc64el': '10', 's390x': '0'}>
check-config: FAIL (y != m): CONFIG_LIBCRC32C policy<{'amd64': 'm', 'arm64': 'm', 'armhf': 'm', 'i386': 'm', 'ppc64el': 'm', 's390x': 'm'}>
check-config: FAIL (y != m): CONFIG_NFSD policy<{'amd64': 'm', 'arm64': 'm', 'armhf': 'm', 'i386': 'm', 'ppc64el': 'm', 's390x': 'm'}>
check-config: FAIL (y != n): CONFIG_BOOTPARAM_HUNG_TASK_PANIC policy<{'amd64': 'n', 'arm64': 'n', 'armhf': 'n', 'i386': 'n', 'ppc64el': 'n', 's390x': 'n'}>
check-config: FAIL (y != n): CONFIG_BOOTPARAM_SOFTLOCKUP_PANIC policy<{'amd64': 'n', 'arm64': 'n', 'armhf': 'n', 'i386': 'n', 'ppc64el': 'n', }>
check-config: FAIL (y != n): CONFIG_DEBUG_RT_MUTEXES policy<{'amd64': 'n', 'arm64': 'n', 'armhf': 'n', 'i386': 'n', 'ppc64el': 'n', 's390x': 'n'}>
check-config: FAIL (- != n): CONFIG_UNWINDER_GUESS policy<{'amd64': 'n', 'i386': 'n'}>
check-config: FAIL (y != n): CONFIG_BOOTPARAM_HARDLOCKUP_PANIC policy<{'amd64': 'n', 'i386': 'n', 'ppc64el': 'n'}>
check-config: FAIL (y != n): CONFIG_PROVE_LOCKING policy<{'amd64': 'n', 'arm64': 'n', 'armhf': 'n', 'i386': 'n', 'ppc64el': 'n', 's390x': 'n'}>
check-config: FAIL (y != m): CONFIG_CRYPTO_CCM policy<{'amd64': 'm', 'arm64': 'm', 'armhf': 'm', 'i386': 'm', 'ppc64el': 'm', 's390x': 'm'}>
check-config: FAIL (y != m): CONFIG_NFS_V4 policy<{'amd64': 'm', 'arm64': 'm', 'armhf': 'm', 'i386': 'm', 'ppc64el': 'm', 's390x': 'm'}>
check-config: FAIL (y != n): CONFIG_PAGE_EXTENSION policy<{'amd64': 'n', 'arm64': 'n', 'armhf': 'y', 'i386': 'y', 'ppc64el': 'n', 's390x': 'n'}>
check-config: FAIL (y != n): CONFIG_FAULT_INJECTION policy<{'amd64': 'n', 'arm64': 'n', 'armhf': 'n', 'i386': 'n', 'ppc64el': 'n', 's390x': 'n'}>
check-config: FAIL (y != n): CONFIG_DEBUG_SPINLOCK policy<{'amd64': 'n', 'arm64': 'n', 'armhf': 'n', 'i386': 'n', 'ppc64el': 'n', 's390x': 'n'}>
check-config: FAIL (y != n): CONFIG_MODULE_FORCE_LOAD policy<{'amd64': 'n', 'arm64': 'n', 'armhf': 'n', 'i386': 'n', 'ppc64el': 'n', 's390x': 'n'}>
check-config: FAIL (y != n): CONFIG_PANIC_ON_OOPS policy<{'amd64': 'n', 'arm64': 'n', 'armhf': 'n', 'i386': 'n', 'ppc64el': 'n', 's390x': 'n'}> note<keep working if at all possible>

check-config: FAIL (y != m): CONFIG_IP_SCTP policy<{'amd64': 'm', 'arm64': 'm', 'armhf': 'm', 'i386': 'm', 'ppc64el': 'm', 's390x': 'm'}>
check-config: FAIL (y != m): CONFIG_NFS_FS policy<{'amd64': 'm', 'arm64': 'm', 'armhf': 'm', 'i386': 'm', 'ppc64el': 'm', 's390x': 'm'}>
check-config: FAIL (y != n): CONFIG_PSTORE_CONSOLE policy<{'amd64': 'n', 'arm64': 'n', 'armhf': 'y', 'i386': 'n', 'ppc64el': 'n', }>
check-config: FAIL (y != n): CONFIG_KASAN policy<{'amd64': 'n', 'arm64': 'n', 's390x': 'n'}>
check-config: FAIL (y != n): CONFIG_UBSAN policy<{'amd64': 'n', 'arm64': 'n', 'armhf': 'n', 'i386': 'n', 'ppc64el': 'n', 's390x': 'n'}>
check-config: FAIL (y != m): CONFIG_NFS_V3 policy<{'amd64': 'm', 'arm64': 'm', 'armhf': 'm', 'i386': 'm', 'ppc64el': 'm', 's390x': 'm'}>
check-config: FAIL (y != n): CONFIG_DEBUG_MUTEXES policy<{'amd64': 'n', 'arm64': 'n', 'armhf': 'n', 'i386': 'n', 'ppc64el': 'n', 's390x': 'n'}>
check-config: FAIL (y != m): CONFIG_CRYPTO_CMAC policy<{'amd64': 'm', 'arm64': 'm', 'armhf': 'm', 'i386': 'm', 'ppc64el': 'm', 's390x': 'm'}>
check-config: FAIL (y != n): CONFIG_DEBUG_SHIRQ policy<{'amd64': 'n', 'arm64': 'n', 'armhf': 'n', 'i386': 'n', 'ppc64el': 'n', 's390x': 'n'}>
check-config: FAIL (y != n): CONFIG_WQ_WATCHDOG policy<{'amd64': 'n', 'arm64': 'n', 'armhf': 'n', 'i386': 'n', 'ppc64el': 'n', 's390x': 'n'}>
check-config: FAIL (y != n): CONFIG_SLUB_DEBUG_ON policy<{'amd64': 'n', 'arm64': 'n', 'armhf': 'n', 'i386': 'n', 'ppc64el': 'n', 's390x': 'n'}>
check-config: FAIL (n != y): CONFIG_MODULE_SRCVERSION_ALL policy<{'amd64': 'y', 'arm64': 'y', 'armhf': 'y', 'i386': 'y', 'ppc64el': 'y', 's390x': 'y'}>
check-config: FAIL (y != m): CONFIG_NFS_V2 policy<{'amd64': 'm', 'arm64': 'm', 'armhf': 'm', 'i386': 'm', 'ppc64el': 'm', 's390x': 'm'}>
check-config: FAIL (y != n): CONFIG_DEBUG_ATOMIC_SLEEP policy<{'amd64': 'n', 'arm64': 'n', 'armhf': 'n', 'i386': 'n', 'ppc64el': 'n', 's390x': 'n'}>
check-config: FAIL (y != n): CONFIG_KCOV policy<{'amd64': 'n', 'arm64': 'n', 'armhf': 'n', 'ppc64el': 'n', 's390x': 'n'}>
check-config: FAIL (y != n): CONFIG_DEBUG_PAGEALLOC policy<{'amd64': 'n', 'arm64': 'n', 'i386': 'n', 'ppc64el': 'n', 's390x': 'n'}>
check-config: FAIL (y != n): CONFIG_DEBUG_OBJECTS policy<{'amd64': 'n', 'arm64': 'n', 'armhf': 'n', 'i386': 'n', 'ppc64el': 'n', 's390x': 'n'}>
check-config: FAIL (y != m): CONFIG_CRYPTO_MD4 policy<{'amd64': 'm', 'arm64': 'm', 'armhf': 'm', 'i386': 'm', 'ppc64el': 'm', 's390x': 'm'}>
check-config: FAIL (y != n): CONFIG_MODULE_FORCE_UNLOAD policy<{'amd64': 'n', 'arm64': 'n', 'armhf': 'n', 'i386': 'n', 'ppc64el': 'n', 's390x': 'n'}>
check-config: FAIL (- != y): CONFIG_VMAP_STACK policy<{'amd64': 'y', 'arm64': 'y', 's390x': 'y'}>
check-config: FAIL (y != m): CONFIG_DLM policy<{'amd64': 'm', 'arm64': 'm', 'armhf': 'm', 'i386': 'm', 'ppc64el': 'm', 's390x': 'm'}>
check-config: FAIL (- != y): CONFIG_CIFS_FSCACHE policy<{'amd64': 'y', 'arm64': 'y', 'armhf': 'y', 'i386': 'y', 'ppc64el': 'y', 's390x': 'y'}>
check-config: FAIL (y != n): CONFIG_DEBUG_LOCK_ALLOC policy<{'amd64': 'n', 'arm64': 'n', 'armhf': 'n', 'i386': 'n', 'ppc64el': 'n', 's390x': 'n'}>


check-config: FAIL (y != n): CONFIG_DEBUG_LOCK_ALLOC policy<{'amd64': 'n', 'arm64': 'n', 'armhf': 'n', 'i386': 'n', 'ppc64el': 'n', 's390x': 'n'}>
check-config: FAIL (- != y): CONFIG_NFS_FSCACHE policy<{'amd64': 'y', 'arm64': 'y', 'armhf': 'y', 'i386': 'y', 'ppc64el': 'y', 's390x': 'y'}>
check-config: FAIL (y != m): CONFIG_CIFS policy<{'amd64': 'm', 'arm64': 'm', 'armhf': 'm', 'i386': 'm', 'ppc64el': 'm', 's390x': 'm'}>
check-config: 10395/10441 checks passed -- exit 1
debian/rules.d/4-checks.mk:24: recipe for target 'config-prepare-check-generic' failed
make: *** [config-prepare-check-generic] Error 1
```

Any suggestion or pointers ?